# Docker compose creating service twice

Tags: docker

I have a set of docker-compose files that run perfectly fine on one laptop. I've now tried them on a new laptop, and it tries to bring up the same service twice:

```
Creating gamersplane-mysql ... 
Creating gamersplane-mysql ... error

ERROR: for gamersplane-mysql  Cannot start service mysql: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint gamersplane-mysql (b34a05daf391646eb679288eefcaf855c20e62c4413289854388bfa0944de480): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:3306: bind: address already in use
```

If I run a `docker ps -a`, it shows the service as `CREATED`, but running `docker ps` doesn't show the container as running.

My main docker compose:

```
version: '3.6'

volumes:
  mysql_db:
    driver: local
    name: gp_mysql_db

services:
  mysql:
    container_name: gamersplane-mysql
    image: mysql:5.7
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    volumes:
      # - ./docker/mysql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - mysql_db:/var/lib/mysql
```

With an extension file:

```
version: '3.6'

services:
  mysql:
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test123
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=test123
```

As docker is supposed to behave the same regardless of the system it's on, I can't tell what's wrong.

Comment: sure there is not something running? restart? lsof -i :3306 ?

Comment: Yah, I began wondering about that... first time I ran it, didn't see anything, but then restarted, and now mysqld is showing up on 3306, which makes sense. I disabled it, restarted again, and of course it's working. I appreciate the thought!

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comment, I ran `sudo isof -i :3306`. It didn't show anything at first, but after restarting, `mysqld` showed up on that port. I shut it down, restarted again to be safe, and now my compose file is starting up.

Comment: some services bring themselves back to life and some docker containers will restart by default upon reboot! it can get confusing quickly.....